# Problems loading a text file into RichText (C#)

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I'm having trouble loading a file into a RichText control.

First, there are no events in the designer to accomodate drag/drop, so I put these handlers in the form initialization. 
Second, the DragEnter() event does not seem to identify text files properly, so dropping is disabled in the RichText (it works fine for a ListBox).
Third, if I get the RT to load the file, it displays an icon/filename inside the RT text area. I cant find any references to this behavior, and can't turn it off.

This code does NOT work:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RT.AllowDrop = true;
    RT.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(RT_DragEnter);
    RT.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(RT_DragDrop);
}

private void RT_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {

   // when a text file is dragged to this control, GetDataPresent() returns FALSE.
   // this seems to be regardless of the file extension. File is ASCII text only.

   // this code DOES work if the underlying control is a ListBox.

   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
   else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void RT_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {
    string[] filenames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    if (null != filenames){

        // when the file is loaded, the RT also displays an icon for the file,
        // with the filename, inside the text area ... ?

        RT.LoadFile(filenames[0],RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```

In order to get the RT to load a dropped file properly, I use a timer to load the RT outside of the
DragDrop() event:

```
public string FileToLoad;

private void RT_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {
   // allow anything:

   //if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
   //else
        //e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void RT_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e) {
    string[] filenames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    if (null != filenames){
        FileToLoad = filenames[0];
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    if (FileToLoad.Length > 0)
    {
        RT.LoadFile(FileToLoad, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        FileToLoad = "";
    }
 }
```

The latter has the RichText loading the file properly, but this seems like a long way around the block to get LoadFile() to work as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Woukdn't it be easier to load the file into a string and then load the string into the rtfbox?

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.

Comment: Are you trying to load rich text files or just plain text files?  Code works, for the most part.  Change your DragEnter to use `if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))`

Comment: RichTextBox is one of the last remaining pieces of OLE that are still functional.  It supports D+D out of the box, you are seeing the "package" view of the file.  A crazy OLE thingamabob that nobody ever understood.  The bug in your DragEnter event is pretty evident.

Comment: .The change to GetDataPresent() worked, but overall the RTBox is opening files as packages, with clickable icons that launch an external text editor. Weird behavior, and I will probably use a listbox, even though they load text MUCH MUCH slower. thanks to all.